# Replace words from querystring with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, asp-classic

the string is = "Reg.asp?q=RG_Price=5000*8000,Activated=1"

and i want to replace "RG_Price=5000*8000" with that "Price BETWEEN 5000 AND 8000".

Is that possible with Regular Expressions in ASP ?

Comment: please add asp.net tag or asp-classic tag whichever is appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Sure (now with VBScript instead of C#):

```
Dim queryString, replacedString
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = ".+RG_Price=(\d+)\*(\d+).*"

replacedString = regEx.Replace(queryString, "Price BETWEEN $1 AND $2")
```

Comment: This is not working in ASP.

Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01c2'

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'regEx.replace'

Comment: But in VBScript, it should work the same way: the object is still a `RegExp`, you set the `Pattern` attribute the same way, and the `Replace()` method still takes two arguments, the original string and the value to substitute for the matched pattern. (Although in the example above, queryString hasn't yet been set; it would need to be set to the queryString you pulled off the URL farther up in the code.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regular expression:

```
^[^?]*\?(?:[^&]*&)*q=RG_Price=(\d+)\*(\d+)
```

and replace the match with `"Price BETWEEN $1 AND $2"`.

But I don’t know ASP.NET so I cannot give you a working example.